# file upload function is working on localhost but i am not able to upload files on online server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, phpmyadmin

I am developing a web application in which i need to upload images. when i upload images on localhost(localserver) its working 100%, but its not working on online server when i upload the application. Kindly help me swiftly so i met project deadlines swiftly.

```
include 'Connection.php';
$dir = "uploads";
$id = "SELECT mid from medicine ORDER BY mid DESC limit 1";
 $id = mysqli_query($con,$id);
 $id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id);
 $mid = $id['mid'];
 if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
    { 
        $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
        {
    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]))
       {
         $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
       }
         else
       {

  if(@copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],$dir.'/'.$_FILES['image']['name'][$i]))
   {
        $img = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];      
       mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into images (dir,mid)Values('$img',$mid)");
       $messages[] = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i].'uploaded';
                }
                else
                {
            $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['image']['name'][$i].' Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you share error you are getting. error log inside /var/logs/apache2/error.log. Which server you are using. can share screenshot of error.

Comment: Did you configure permission for directory upload? example for linux is 775.

Comment: yes I configure all permisions.

Comment: aviboy2006 
I could not find error you may check 
http://www.haiderpharmacy.com/Admin/AddMedicine.php
username awais
password awais123